# Adding classes to Blazor(Razor) Validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I know things are still pretty early in the Blazor development track, but I'm wondering if anyone has come across a way to apply classes to a Blazor (Razor) validation message? Here's a sample of code.

```
        <EditForm Model="@Employee" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-3">Last Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <InputText id="lastName" @bind-Value="@Employee.LastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last name" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Employee.LastName)" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'd like to be able to add a `text-danger`, `col-sm-8` or other classes to the validation message. I already know that I could do it with CSS using the default `validation-error` class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested above, you can subclass the `ValidationMessage` component class... I'll give you a simpler solution, since I prefer not to have a myriad of classes on my projects just for changing the appearance a little.

Just wrap the `ValidatorMessage` with a `div` and apply classes to it:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 text-danger">
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Employee.LastName)" />
</div>
```

Anyway, what the `ValidationMessage` component does (by code) is rendering a simple `div` with the class "`validation-message`" so, if you have problems with any style not being applied, take into account that you can force styles using the right CSS selectors (and maybe some `!important` tags...).

Comment: I did think about this but I didn't try it. I was wondering if it would add unnecessary spacing into the form if there are empty divs?

Comment: It's not an empty div, it's a wrapping div... Anyway it won't add any extra space if you don't apply margin or padding to it.

Comment: Super simple and works well. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you can't add a class, but you can add styles:

```
<ValidationMessage
    For="..."
    style="color: #dc3545!important;
           flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
           max-width: 66.666667%;" />
```

You can also override the `validation-message` class as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#code-try-11:%7E:text=Control%20the%20style%20of%20validation%20messages).